# Whats the difference between these two segments of code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, I am wondering whats the difference between these two segments of code - other than just syntax differences?

```
BBDataStore* tempDataStore = [[BBDataStore alloc] initWithDataExpiry:DATA_EXPIRY_TIME];
    self.dataStore = tempDataStore;
```

and

```
self.dataStore = [[BBDataStore alloc] initWithDataExpiry:DATA_EXPIRY_TIME];
```

`Self.dataStore` is a property of `BBDataStore`.

From what I can see - there is no difference here.

In the first example - we eventually assigned `tempDataStore`  to `self.dataStore` - which is an instance of `BBDatastore`.

In the second example - we effectively do the same thing... not so?

Comment: i think there is no different in both of the two lines.

Comment: In First case first line creating object and tempDataStore has reference to it, when second line execute, self.dataStore also point to the same object. hence reference count will increase. and when tempDataStore scope will end there will be only one reference to the object and that will be self.dataStore. And in second case there is only one pointer reference to object and that is self.datastore

Comment: There is no effective difference.  If compiled with an optimizing compiler the two would likely generate the same code.  (A debug-mode compiler would be different since the named variable would have to be made debugger-accessible and hence would probably not be register-optimized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BBDataStore* tempDataStore = [[BBDataStore alloc] initWithDataExpiry:DATA_EXPIRY_TIME];
self.dataStore = tempDataStore;
```

This is holding instance of BBDataStore into tempDataStore. And you are assigning tempDataStore to other object say self.dataStore.

```
self.dataStore = [[BBDataStore alloc] initWithDataExpiry:DATA_EXPIRY_TIME];
```

This is the direct initialization of self.dataStore.

Difference is only that in first way one more variable come in picture which also consumes memory bit. Why should we consume memory even we have handy approach for initiazation. So you should avoid first way and go with second approach which is very general and appropriate too.

Comment: Thanks - that cleared it up for me nicely. I prefer the second was. Since I am using ARC - managing reference counts is done for me and nothing I need to worry about right? (In the basic memory management terms )

Comment: Yes you don't need to worry about it. but you should take care not to adding place holder / junk variable for temporary task right ? :) .Go for second approach in all case.

Comment: @Tander URW always :)

Comment: I would disagree with "one more variable".  In both cases the value will be assigned to a local variable, in one case one explicitly named by the programmer, in the other case one generated by the compiler.  Very likely the (optimized) generated code would be identical.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ARC in your code, both the statements are effectively doing the same (compiler magic happens which ensure both statements end up with same result).

If this were manual memory management with `self.dataStore` declared as a `retain` property then,

**Code1**: Will be ideal way to assign the `retain` property with an object. This will keep the reference count of the created object to 1 (Your property will be the owner). So when the ivar for the `retain` property is released in `dealloc` the memory gets cleared.

```
BBDataStore* tempDataStore = [[BBDataStore alloc] initWithDataExpiry:DATA_EXPIRY_TIME];
self.dataStore = tempDataStore;
//This will ensure memory does not leak, reference count will get reduced by 1
[tempDataStore release];
```

**Code2**: Will have reference count of the object as 2 (One from `init` and other from `retain` property). Even after releasing the ivar in `dealloc` this code will potentially leak memory since the temporary object reference is not available to call `release` method.

```
//This created object will have reference count 2
self.dataStore = [[BBDataStore alloc] initWithDataExpiry:DATA_EXPIRY_TIME];
//reference to temporary object is not available hence cannot call release
```

So in this case for the ARC mechanism the compiler will insert certain lines of code to ensure that memory of your object does not leak (It will create a temporary reference to object, insert release statement on this after assigning to the property, similar to code1).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In First case first line creates an object and `tempDataStore` has reference to it, when second line execute, `self.dataStore` also point to the same object. hence reference count will increase and two pointers will point to same object. And when `tempDataStore` scope will end there will be only one reference to the object and that will be `self.dataStore`. And in second case there is only one pointer reference to object and that is `self.datastore`